# Holes on bottom side of tomato

Tags: diagnosis, tomatoes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cracks on Bottom Side of Tomato](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/935/cracks-on-bottom-side-of-tomato)

This may be related to my prior question about [cracks on the bottom side of tomatoes](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/935/cracks-on-bottom-side-of-tomato).  A few plants I'm growing have appeared with holes on the bottom side as they've started to ripen.  Is this potentially related to [catfacing](http://gardener.shoutwiki.com/wiki/Catfacing) the plant experienced earlier in the season or could it possibly be related to a bug or pest?

[image]

Comment: Are these pictures of the catfaced tomatoes in your earlier question after ripening? This looks exactly like the other question

Comment: These are ones that were not catfaced originally, all of  those were disposed of.  As these have ripened the holes have developed as in the picture.

Comment: Alright. I don't know much about tomato diseases (although I grow lots of them, never had one rot out on me), so I'll let others decide if it's a bug/different disease or catface again.

Comment: Since it looks similar, the condition is caused by injury to the blossoms, and we've established that your plants did have catfacing (so we know that at least *some* blossoms were damaged), I'm going with catfacing again.

Comment: @Jakkwylde, Apart from fruit damage, are the plants healthy, leaves look good, etc? A photo of a complete plant might help...

Answer (score 2):

This can be caused due to sudden vegetable / fruit growth in a short period of time.  It can be actually caused by several factors:

-fertilizing too much or too late in the season

-weather plays a huge role, has it been very dry where you are from with sudden rain?

-or has the temperature dropped during the night so much that there is a big change from the day temp to the night temp